# Want to run a custom gradle task only when running Unit test

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

How to set up gradle to run a particular custom copy task, only when running unit tests?

**EDIT**

I want to run these tasks when i press build,  i. e only in the  flavor of the build with unit test execution included.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've finally found the solution, with the help of [this documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Android-tasks) which presents all the tasks that run during `build`, `test`, `release` etc. in a very concise manner. So by making tasks `clean`, `preBuild` depend on my `copyTask` I can ensure that the copy task is run every time the project is cleaned or built.

But since I don't want to run this during building or cleaning process but want to run it when I only run tests, I identified a task that compiles release unit test sources called the `compileReleaseUnitTestSources` but just mentioning it in build.gradle as

```
compileReleaseUnitTestSources.dependsOn(myCopyTask)
```

doesn't actually work, because gradle will give an error saying it cannot find the task `compileReleaseUnitTestSources` as for some reason that task is not available yet. Instead by enclosing it in a `afterEvaluate` block we can ensure that this block is executed after all tasks are evaluated, that way we have access to that task now, So finally I added this to my build.gradle

```
afterEvaluate {
    compileReleaseUnitTestSources.dependsOn(copyResDirectoryToClasses)
}
```

All the answers here mention to use the `dependsOn` keyword to attach my task to another task that is run during general build/test execution, but none of them mentioned how to go around the problem where gradle is not able to find the tasks even though you know for sure that these tasks were available and run during build/test execution.

Answer (score 3):

you have to set up a "customCopyTask" and make the "test-task" which does the unittests depend on the "customCopyTask" like this

```
task customCopyTask(type: Copy) {
    from sourceSets.test.resources
    into sourceSets.test.output.classesDir
}
test.dependsOn customCopyTask
```

Comment: i understand setting up the unit test task separately and when i run that task make it depend on my copy task what i want to do is have the copy task run when I execute unit test in android studio by right clicking on the unit test and selecting run test

Comment: correct. depend means must have been executed before. example: "run" depends on "compile". "compile" must have been executed before "run" executes

Comment: yes i understand that how do I make sure that this test task executes when I run build in android studio for example?

Comment: here the `test` is not avaiable you need to enclose it in a `afterEvaluate` block in order run that statement `test.dependsOn`

Answer (score 1):

You can make some task finalizing another, in that case this task will run only if another one was called, right after it. This could be done as:

```
task runUnitTest << {
    println 'running tests'
}

task copyTestResults << {
    println 'copying results'
}

//make copyTestResults finalize runUnitTest
runUnitTest.finalizedBy copyTestResults
```

You can read about it in the official [user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#N10F3E).

Additionally, if your unit test could be up-to-date and you don't want to run you copy task in that case, you can check the test task status and skip copy-task, as:

```
task copyTestResults {
    doFirst {
        //chtck anothe task status and skip this one if it didn't actually work
        if (!tasks.getByName("runUnitTest").getState().didWork) {
            throw new StopExecutionException();
        }
    }
    doLast{
        println 'copying results'
    }
}
```

Or, if you just need to run copy-task before unit tests, make the test task depending on copy-task by setting it's `dependsOn` property, read about it with a number og examples [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:task_dependencies)

Comment: well will doing this automatically execute the tasks when I right click my unit test method and click on run unit test?

Comment: @Bhargav if you apply it to task, which running your test and run them with gradle, when sure

Comment: how do i find out which tasks run when click run unit test?

Comment: @Bhargav have you tried to look at the logs? If test are runned by Gradle, then the project and tasks names are logged

Comment: Yes sorry I looked at it, I see that this task `prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies` is run but when I put this line `prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies.dependsOn(copyResDirectoryToClasses)` in build.gradle(module:app) I get this error `Could not find property 'prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies' on project ':app'.`

Comment: @Bhargav first check the order. Task has to be declared before the setting it's property. Or you can set `dependsOn` in task definition. If there is no task definition, you may try to find it by name as `tasks.getByName("prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies").dependsOn copyResDirectoryToClasses`

Comment: I think that task comes with com.android.application plugin

Comment: @Bhargav then you can allocate it via `tasks`

Comment: `assembleDebug.dependsOn(copyResDirectoryToClasses)` works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96867/discussion-between-bhargav-and-stanislav).